# Porque obtengo separamientos por defecto al usar expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver en la imagen no he definido distancias entre si pero este lo hace.
como podria solucionar este problema? aca dejare todo el codigo

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Progreso de tus clases",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.065,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/Fondo GdR 2.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
              horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
          child: Column(
            
            children: [
            
            Text(
              "Pendientes",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.055,
              ),
            ),
            
           
              Expanded(
                child: _listViewPendientes(),
                
              ),
              
            Text(
              "Completos",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.055,
                
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

incluso para simplificar aun mas habia remplazado ese _listviewPendientes por un texto sencillo y definitivamente es el widget expanded. el problema es que necesito poner mas contenido debajo de el y si quito el expanded pues no se vera el contenido del listview builder. disculpen soy nuevo con flutter.

Comment: Tal y como lo estás haciendo, tendría quizás más sentido que añadieras un ListView normal en lugar de un Column y que donde has puesto el _listViewPendientes() usaras un column o pusieras directamente todos los widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Un ListView usará tanto espacio como su Widget padre se lo permita, en el caso de que su elemento padre sea un Expanded, el ListViewe tomará todo el espacio disponible.

Por consiguiente la solución es usar un Flexible en lugar de un expanded con la propiedad fit loose para que el widget hijo utilice únicamente el espacio necesario:

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.loose,
  child: _listViewPendientes(),
),
```

Así mismo, el ListView debe tener la propiedad shrinkWrap: true para que este use únicamente el espacio necesario para mostrar sus elementos:

```
ListView<ElementoClase> _listViewPendientes(){
  return child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap:true,
    //builder e itemCount
    .
    .
    .
  );
}
```

**Nota:**
Este método es útil si quieres mostrar pocos elementos, si tu ListView contiene demasíados elementos podrías experimentar lentitud.